# Does Detect Magic detect the effects of Rebuke Undead?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e

If an undead creature is under a caster's control by Rebuke Undead (as applied to a weaker undead under the Control Undead threshold), would a casting of Detect Magic give any indication of that?

Comment: …And if it *can* be detected then it can probably be dispelled or suppressed. (That's a reminder for me (and other users) for when or if I answer this question.)

Comment: It is a Supernatural, so only antimagic field *might* affect it in that regard - dispelling won't work. This doesn't answer the detection question however - which probably hinges on what the duration on it is.

Comment: when you say under their control, do you mean as a result of *Command* Undead (the parallel to destroy undead v.s. turn undead) or mearly the weaker rebuking effect?  I don't think cowering in awe is generally described as 'control'...

Comment: The higher effect of Rebuke Undead, which controls the undead. I worded it this way on account of distinguishing it from the relevant spells.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**According to FAQ – yes.**

Turning/rebuking undead is a supernatural ability.

> Supernatural abilities are magical and go away in an antimagic field
>   but are not subject to spell resistance, counterspells, or to being
>   dispelled by dispel magic.

Unfortunately, the rules don´t say (as far as I know, at least), whether an effect created by a supernatural ability has a magical aura that can be detected by the spell *detect magic*. 
Also, the description of the spell only refers to spells and magic items.

In the FAQs I found this entry:

> *Can you use detect magic to detect supernatural effects? For example,
>   can it detect a wildshaped druid?* 
>   - Supernatural abilities are magical,
>   and thus their effects would produce magical auras. Although the
>   detect magic spell doesn’t have a line entry for supernatural effect,
>   you can use the same line as “Magic item (caster level)”—a
>   supernatural effect’s caster level is equal to the creature’s Hit Dice
>   unless noted otherwise (MM 315).

Following this, detect magic would reveal a magic aura on an undead creature which is under the effect of a cleric´s turn/rebuke undead ability.

Comment: So what school aura does the effect have? You may want to find [a better source](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60044/what-is-wrong-with-the-dd-3-5-faq)

Comment: @Please stop being evil I know that the FAQ is not reliabe. That´s why I pointed out, it is only a "yes according to FAQ". I just haven´t a better source here. Maybe someone else has ...?

Answer (score 2):

## No one knows

There are several questions with unclear answers here that the ultimate answer depends on.

### Can *detect magic* detect supernatural abilities?

As [another answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168865/14848) notes, the FAQ says 'yes'.  It, however, does not explain all the details necessary for such a ruling to work: for example, it does not explain how to calculate the school of a supernatural ability, nor on which creature(s) or object(s) the magical aura is present.

*Detect Magic* itself seem ambivalent on the issue, both noting "Presence or absence of magical auras" under the first round effects without qualifiers, yet also noting "Outsiders and elementals are not magical in themselves, but if they are summoned, the conjuration spell registers". Furthermore, the spell states "A magical aura lingers after its original source dissipates (in the case of a spell) or is destroyed (in the case of a magic item)".

In argument *against* the spell detecting supernatural abilities, there is the lack of support in the table for that, the fact that almost all outsiders and elementals have supernatural abilities (so one would mention that, rather than summoning spells), and the fact that lingering auras have rules for item and spell sources, but not for supernatural ability sources.

In argument *for* the spell detecting supernatural abilities, there is the way that the spell description seems to implicitly assume that items and spells are, like, somehow all of 'magic' and the generalization that *detect magic*, then, is probably supposed to detect that.  There is also the weird consequence that if Su abilities *don't* register to *detect magic* that means that they don't have magical auras, which can be very counter-intuitive, particularly if such a ruling were extended to Sp abilities, which are technically also not spells. There's also the fact that the FAQ thinks this is the way it works or should work or something.

If the answer to this question is 'no', *detect magic* cannot detect the effects of rebuke undead.  If yes, we need to address more questions.

### What is rebuke undead's duration?

Again, this is not clear.  We know that you can take an action and that afterwards effects may persist for a while.  We do not know whether those effects are consequences of instantaneous-like magic or not.  That is to say, if rebuke undead works like *fireball*, the *effects* are not magic even though the *ability* is.  In that case, you could see the magic of a Cleric *rebuking* undead but not anything on an undead that *had been* rebuked-- there would be nothing to see in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

### I would say <strike>no</strike> yes (as the question is for commanded creatures, shame on me), but read the edit

[Peregrin Took's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168865/63733) covers really well the general rule on supernatural effects, **and it applies to commanded undead** (or any other creature) as you maintain a bond with those entities so you can order them for as long as you want, but a rebuked creature only cowers.

However, if you understand the effect as a long time effect, which could be dispelled (by RAW that only applies to turned creatures, not rebuked ones) you could detect some kind of aura from them.

Is like a fireball or an attack with a magic weapon, the damage is magical, but the burn/scar in your body isn't.

**Edit:** I want to emphasize that **I do think** that controlled creatures might emanate some kind of aura, but rebuked ones don't. Most spells have a duration specified because you can dispell the effect by magical means and/or some way to interact with the affected target, while Rebuke (and Destroy to be fair) is an instantaneous action with a consequence, like the *Command* spell when you issue the *Drop* command.

> You  give  the  subject  a  single  command,  which it obeys to the best of its ability at its earliest  opportunity.  You  may  select  from  the following options
>
> *Drop*:   On   its   turn,   the   subject   drops   whatever it is holding. It can’t pick up any dropped item until its next turn

As the sword being in the floor is a consequence of a spell and not the spell effect, you can't dispell the finished order to make the the sword return to its owner hand.

In fact, we could even argue about the descrption of turning/rebuking undead meaning that the affected creatures are simply "moved" in the same way a politician "moves" peopel with their speeches:

> **Turn  or  Rebuke  Undead  (Su):**  Any  cleric,  regardless  of  align-ment,  has  the  power  to  affect  undead  creatures  (such  as  skeletons,  zombies, ghosts, and vampires) **by channeling the power of his faith through  his  holy  (or  unholy)  symbol**

In which case none of the cleric's magical power is proyected to any creature, acting more like a megaphone to influence it's targets in the same way Eagle's Splendor buff a Diplomacy roll, but I'm not really set into this interpretation of the rule.

Comment: Thus the underlying question is whether the duration of turn or rebuke undead is instantaneous or permanent. I've always played that it was instantaneous with the understanding that the duration of *everything*, unless stated otherwise, is, essentially, instantaneous. (That is, for many things wherein no duration is given, you do it (e.g. swing a sword, turn undead, sneeze, yodel) and, afterward, only the consequences of having done it remain. You've to deal with those consequences (e.g. the wound, the effect, the disease, the echo) because it's just *too late* to stop the event.)

Comment: That's exactly my point here. Turning gives you counterplay to that mechanic, but rebuking (or even commanding) doesn't give you any appart from destroying the subjects. I compared the effect with the spell Fear, which indicates a duration, but as a spell is dispellable.

Comment: @MrTakeru I can see your point. But I would argue, that the duration is as long as the time the effect lasts (in the case of rebuke: 10 rounds). I think the fact that an evil cleric is able to dispel a good cleric’s turning effect supports this assumption, since you cannot dispel something with an instantaneous effect. (I know, for some obscure reason it´s not true vice versa - a good cleric can't dispel an evil cleric's rebuke effect ...)

Comment: @PeregrinTook When a cleric uses dispel turning, though, that needn't be read as the cleric dispelling the turning in the same way that a *dispel magic* can end a *wall of fire.* It can also be read as the dispel turning ending the *effect* of the turning, the same as if the undead under were lit on fire (a successful turning) and were then doused with water (successful dispel turning). Reading other *duration but* turning uses similarly can lead to reading all uses of turning and rebuking as instantaneous *and* provide some much needed consistency on this issue.

Comment: @PeregrinTook That's the main thing, an evil cleric can do some kind of dispellish thing against good energy or even protect against it effects, but you can't do the same on the other direction (let's keep in mind that turning isn't exclusive to undead, even if it is the most prominent case). I get that a good cleric wouldn't even thing of buffing an undead, but the can't counter the rebuking nor controlling in any form.

Comment: @heyicanchan So you are ok with some effect that makes someone not only obey you but also makes your mental commands transfer to it's mind without actually presenting on that someone? Like making mentioned things "natural properties" of that someone.

Comment: @annoyingimp I'm sorry, but I don't understand what *presenting on someone* means. What I do know is that, as written, once command is established *via* rebuking, the only way it ends is by the commander relinquishing command *because* the commander later commands more HD. Commanding *via* rebuking doesn't seem to end when the commander dies, when the commanded creature dies, when another commander commands the *same* creature, or from any other effect that I'm aware of. It's *that* underwritten, and—perhaps purely by accident—one of the game's most severe and long-lasting effects.

Comment: @heyicanchan I mean, if it is permanent, it acts like magical "radio" for your commands. If it is instantaneous, then it  builds that "radio" into the creature's nature for some reason. The later breaks my (at least) suspension of disbelieve.

Comment: @annoyingimp Given the difficult-to-get-rid-of nature of the effect of successfully rebuking to command a creature, the analogy *It's like installing a radio control into the victim's head* is actually incredibly apt. Essentially, as written, success means that the "radio" remains installed until the commander "switches frequencies" by commanding more undead; the commander can't even voluntarily *end* his command of the victim! The closest the commander can do to ending control without installing more radios in other victims is just not issuing orders to the commanded creature!

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan „He (the evil cleric) may voluntarily relinquish command on any commanded undead creature or creatures in order to command new ones.“ - I wouldn´t interpret this as _he can only relinquish command, if he replaces his commanded undead with others._ I rather think „… in order to command new ones.“ is just stated as an example of a motivation to do so. (Being tired of having those stupid zombies around could be another one. :)

Comment: @PeregrinTook *Voluntarily* there means that newly commanded HD of creatures don't cause the cleric to *automatically* shed previously commanded HD of creatures to make room for the newly commanded HD of creatures, not that there are *other* ways of ending control. So far as I'm aware, like I've said all along, I don't think there is another way of ending control of a commanded creature except by replacement. (A different issue with rebuking is that if no room's made by a full commander for the newly commanded creature it seems that the newly commanded creature is neither commanded nor awed!)